# C# list count returning object null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following model in my asp mvc application

```
 public class StringIntType
 {

    public string str { get; set; }
    public int nbr { get; set; }
    public string par { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
}
```

I run this query

```
  var sql = "select object as str , host as par from table " +
            "where date > '2015-01-01' and date <'2015-01-03' option (recompile)";
```

and map results into this list

```
var myList = (List<StringIntType>)db.Database.SqlQuery<StringIntType>(sql).ToList();
```

The problem is when i try to do some sorting in myList that way

```
 int n = myList.Where(x => x.par.Contains("object")).Count();
```

I get the following error

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object at  x.par.Contains("object")
```

Comment: probably your `myList` is `null` thats why. Perform a null check before directly manipulating it

Comment: Looks like `x.par` is null

Comment: Provided myList is not null, may be there are rows in your table with 'par' column set to null?

Comment: @JPG that was it some columns are null i should add where columns not null

Answer (score 5, accepted):

cause x.par can be null

So you can do like this:

```
int n = myList.Where(x => x.par != null && x.par.Contains("object")).Count();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try setting each x.par to a default value other than null or do a check on x.par for null before calling Contains on it.

Answer (score 2):

`x` or `x.par` might be null :

```
int n = myList.Where(x => x != null &&  x.par != null && x.par.Contains("object")).Count();
```